# jquery mobile history.back() only work for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

currently I have encountered a problem with history. back ().

I have 2 pages, which is pageA.html, pageB.html.

I'm using the following code for go to next page and back to previous page

```
// go to next page
function changePage(url) {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", url, {
    allowSamePageTransition: true,
    transition: 'none',
    showLoadMsg: false,
    reloadPage: false,
    changeHash: true
  })
}

//back to previous page
function backToPreviousPage(){
  alert("back");
  history.back();
}
```

The codes work fine for the first time, as the flow below

First time : pageA > pageB (click on back button once) > pageA

So I have successfully back to pageA again. And here's the problem comes.

Second time : pageA > pageB (first click back button no respond, then click for second time) > pageA

When it comes to third time, I need to click on the back button 3 times then only can make the history.back() work, I can get the alert message, so the backToPrevious function is called.

so the problem is like below:

- 1st navigate : pageA > pageB > pageA (1 click)
- 2nd navigate : pageA > pageB > pageA (2 clicks)
- 3rd naviagate : pageA > pageB > pageA (3 clicks)

and so on....

Ii can't just hardcode navigate back to pageA in the backToPrevious function, because I not only can navigate to pageB from pageA, but also can navigate pageB from other page.

So far I have tried with this

```
history.back(-1);
```

and this

```
<a data-rel="back" href="javascript:history.back(1)" data-theme="a">Back</a>
```

but still can't fix the problem.

Appreciate if anyone can tell me what am i doing wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code.

```
   function changePage() {
     $.mobile.changePage("pageA.html");
     return false;
    }

    function backToPreviousPage(){
     navigator.app.backHistory();

    }
```

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake that not giving full details of my problem. pageB is actually a multi access page, means that i can navigate pageB from pageA, but also can navigaate pageB from pageZ. Do you have any idea on it ?